# How to use header file (.h) with Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've read a lot of posts about this topic, but I don't know sure if I can use this type of files with Android java classes.

I would like to load a big array of floats to use OpenGL to show a 3D model.

To do this, I've a .h file that contains the different arrays. This file is like this:

```
unsigned int numVerts= 123456;

float verts[] = {
//a lot of data here
...
}
```

Then... Is there anyway to load this array into an Android class?

Comment: What does Java question have to do with C or C++?  Either remove the tags or add some more for C# and Ada.

Comment: Not sure what you've read but you can not load a .h file from C into Java. You need to turn it into a .java file if you want to make use of those arrays. What you can do is to write C code and use that from Java via native bindings: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html or you could try to parse the file as text file and build java arrays that way. But that means you're writing a C parser.

Comment: But java files has the 64K limit and the header files are about 8MB =( So, how can I read this data? any idea? Ok, I've just read your updated comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly.  .h files are part of the C language and cannot be used in Java.

There are two real possibilities:

1. If you need to use the constants defined in the .h file, you can create a Java file that defines similar constants.  In fact it is pretty easy, using your favorite scripting language, to do this automatically.
2. Use the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html).  If you need more than the constants -- you are going to call OpenGL functions directly or some such thing -- then you can write your code in C, refer to the .h file, and call the C methods you define, from you Java code.
3. The guy that downvoted this answer insists that there is a third possibility, which I include only for completeness.  You could, from your Android program, read in the .h file, like any other file, and parse it, to get the information that you want.  Doing that would be completely crazy.

Comment: I would say that it can't be used.